# Store Subscript and superscript Values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an Excel file which has superscript and Subscript values of chemical formula etc.

In Mysql I set collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but still its not saving with super/sub scripts.

Please help me (Example: C-1 m<sup>2</sup> N-2)

Comment: Formatting, tag cleanup

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that, the character you are trying to store in the database should be the real "superscript two" ( ² , U+00B2 ) character and not a character "two" formatted by the browser or any kind of text editor (MS Excel included).

Try copying the superscript characters from [here](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) and pasting them in your input. You will see that the character will be stored and displayed correctly by MySQL.