# Laravel RegEx Problem with special-char ² and ³

Tags: regex, laravel

I want to use regex to prohibit certain characters. This works. However, I cannot write superscripts, although they are allowed.

This is my regex:

```
    return [
       'name' => ['regex:/^[^\x27\x22\\@!$&§{\[\]}><;?]+$/']
    ];
```

I want to store name like **"This is the nam 234³"**. But the **"³"** or **"²"** doesn't store.

Comment: I believe this is not a regex problem rather a database issue, check this out to see if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34653433/store-subscript-and-superscript-values-in-mysql

Comment: The Vaildate return false. Thats the Problem. Manually i can store in Database with this character. But the Laravel Validate does not match. It is not a Database problem.

Answer (score -1):

OK, i detect the problem of my regex. I exclude the "Paragraph-Sign". This is the same key as "§".

Comment: This is the same key as "³".

Comment: Maybe you actually need `'regex:/^[^][\x27\x22\\@!$&§{}><;?]+$/u'`? Note the `u` flag.